# how do I copy fluid physics from one object to several

Tags: animation

How do I copy fluid obstacle properties to other objects.  I see that we can copy from active with ridgid body tools but this does not exist for fluid.
Right ?

Answer (score 1):

An option that is available for many settings, not just fluid settings, is to right click <kbd>[image: RMB]</kbd> on the value and choose Copy To Selected. This will copy the value from the active object to all selected objects.

[image: copy to selected]

Comment: Also one can copy them with Ctrl+L menu or Copy Attributes menu addon as these are settings of the Fluid modifier.

Comment: In 2.8 this it seems to not be part of that addon anymore though.

Comment: @copypaste Which part can't you find? The copy to selected is still part of blender 2.80. The Copy attributes addon is also still available - with Ctrl-C. In the make links or copy attributes you want to copy modifiers and then you can use copy to selected on individual settings.

Comment: It works with cmd+L and then modifiers. I did not find another way to copy fluid physics.